# No virtual method fromJson 'com.google.gson.Gson' version 2.9.0

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, nosuchmethoderror

I updated my application `minimum sdk` to `29` from `28`, Also I updated version of `'com.google.code.gson'` library to `'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'`. After updating the version of `'com.google.code.gson'` library I am getting the below error,

*

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
> fromJson(Ljava/io/Reader;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class
> Lcom/google/gson/Gson; or its super classes (declaration of
> 'com.google.gson.Gson' appears in
> /data/app/~~l9WOw15t23rdOauhgbiBUg==/com.edfapay.paysys-W_j-Ejwt1ZQ5BTbYJVDKBw==/base.apk)
> *

I am using retrofit2 library version of,

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.9.0'
```

Comment: can you try using something like this?          

  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'